# Changing the min value of the x axis in Chart control - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, charts

i am currently trying to change the X axis min value on my VB.Net chart, but am having some issues, ive looked around but can't find much on it.

Here is the code i have at the moment with commented values that would be:

```
    Dim c As String() = company.Split(", ") ' 0 code, 1 name ' filename(s)
    Dim t As String = type ' if we are looking at prices or percentage differences
    Dim f() As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString.Split(", ") ' this is to get the file returns first part of the string
    Dim values() As Decimal = getvalues(f(0)) ' 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 for example
    Dim times() As String = gettimes(f(0)) ' 16:04:23, 16:05:39, 16:09:29 etc...


    Chart1.Series.Add(type.ToString)

    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = values.min
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = values.max + (values.max / 10)

    Chart1.Series(0).LegendText = type.ToString
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(times, values)
```

without the 
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = values.min
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = values.max + (values.max / 10)

my chart displays like:
[No Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipoK1.png)

but with the Chartarea added, this happens:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E5we.png)

My goal here is bassicly i want to focus on the top of the bars so you can see the differences between them, starting at a higher x axit value, but it doesnt seem to be working, do i have my code wrong?

Comment: You appear to have your axes reversed. X axis is time, but you're setting the min and max of X (rather than Y) against values.

Comment: ah, so simple, thanks alot